# How can disable SSL peer verification in http client (httpc) in erlang

Tags: ssl, https, erlang, ca

I sent a restfull api request by http client, but i get below error:

```
{error,{failed_connect,[{to_address,{"https://example.com",443}},
{inet,[inet],{tls_alert,"record overflow"}}]}}
```

i found that SSL peer verification made this problem. how can i disable it?

**my code:**

```
test() ->
   inets:start(),
   ssl:start(),
   RequestBody = "",
   Request = {"https://example.com", [{"X-API-CODE",""}, {"Accept","application/json"}, {"access-token",""}], "application/json", RequestBody},
   {ok, {_, _, ResponseBody}} = httpc:request(post, Request, [], []),
   io:format("~st", [ResponseBody]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although disabling verification is not a good idea, but it's possible by using `{ssl, [{verify, verify_none}]}` in the options. 
Example:
`httpc:request(get, {"https://revoked.badssl.com/", []}, [{ssl, [{verify, verify_none}]}], []).`